# Composite Not Null constraint on two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I want to have a constraint in which I make sure that at least of two columns is not null.
Basically, from those two columns, one must contain values.

How can I have a constraint like that?
Is it possible on liquibase? If not, is it possible via SQL or some postgres specific thing?

Comment: Related on answer dba.SE: ["Count NULL values per row"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/205899/3684)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like using `num_nonnulls()` for this:

For at least one not null column:

```
check (num_nonnulls(col1, col2) >= 1)
```

For exactly one not null column:

```
check (num_nonnulls(col1, col2) = 1)
```

Liquibase has not built-in change for check constraints (at least not in the community version), so you will need a `<sql>` change for this:

```
<sql> 
  alter table the_table
    add constraint at_least_one_not_null
    check (num_nonnulls(col1, col2) >= 1)   
</sql>
```

Comment: What a curious function that I hadn't known about.  This is so easy to code in Postgres, I wonder why it is there.  But in any case, I learned something.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, it's really quite handy. There is also `num_nulls()` for the "opposite"

Comment: Thanks for showing this :) I hadn't heard about it, too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `check` constraint.  For at least one non-`NULL` value:

```
check (col1 is not null or col2 is not null)
```

If you need for exactly one to contain values:

```
check (col1 is not null and col2 is null or
       col1 is null and col2 is not null
      )
```

Or in Postgres:

```
check ( (col1 is not null)::int + (col2 is not null)::int = 1 )
```

Comment: I will try this! But it seems promissing, did not come to my mind. You are the man.

Comment: this general logic worked I upvoted your answer but will mark the other one as approved because he also referred how to do it with liquibase