# Liquibase conditions for a composite non null check on multiple columns

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I have a table with 2 columns like so in liquibase.

```
              - column:
                  name: col1
                  type: UUID
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
                    references: 'tab1(id1)'
                    foreignKeyName: 'fk_col1'
              - column:
                  name: col2
                  type: UUID
                  constraints:
                    nullable: true
                    references: 'tab2(id2)'
                    foreignKeyName: 'fk_col2'
```

I would like to define composite non null check on 2 of these columns, with at-least 1 being non null. I found a similiar query answered here: [Composite Not Null constraint on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370232/composite-not-null-constraint-on-two-columns) however , this involves adding a `addCheckConstraint`(https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-check-constraint.html) in Postgresql. We do not have a pro license hence we cannot use this, is there any other way to add this condition?

Comment: You can use the `<sql>` change type. I believe that isn't pro.